# Run Java application with minimal code (hiding the main-method)

Tags: java, reflection

I'm writing a small library that I want to use when teaching Java to people. I'm trying to avoid static methods in the start because they just cause confusion. More specifically I would like to avoid having to instantiate a class to use non-static methods and fields.

An example of a Java program using the library would hopefully be something like this:

```
public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello.");
    }
}
```

I have played around with reflection to instantiate the class, but Eclipse won't even let me define a run configuration even though there is a main method in the library.

The less amount of setup required (IDE settings, boilerplate code, etc...) the better. Is it possible to define a class like this, or something similar, and run it in an IDE? Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Only a suggestion: don't overly protect your pupils. If they can't cope with a `public static void main()` they will run into problems with your approach too.

Comment: @Marged It's more to not scare them away at first, as they are not my pupils, just friends and other people I know that are interested in seeing what code even looks like and how it translates to the screen. But I see what you mean.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thanks for that. Didn't even think of searching for those keywords.

Comment: @ReubenSanders I agree with Marged. You likely want your students to be able to go home and run an example themselves. main() is really the only way to go. Some custom reflection launcher would just confuse the topic.